# Popover over popover, Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, popover

Am trying to open a popover by clicking a button on another popover. I'm not sure how possible it is. [HERE is a Fiddle I created](http://plnkr.co/edit/1kYO5PlSRHfupG1uw7MM?p=preview). Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** [AngularJS 1.2.0 has been released](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/11/angularjs-120-timely-delivery.html) today/yesterday, depending on your timezone.

It makes promises [A+ compliant](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3699) and removes the need of the pesky `$digest` in `$timeout`, and the nested `popover` works perfectly: http://plnkr.co/edit/zHFM9gJ6FLaUj2dWLR3I?p=preview

\o/

---

The problem is a tad bit complicated and not directly in your code, but in `angular-strap.js`, in the line 576.

```js
      popover.getPosition = function () {
        var r = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.getPosition.apply(this, arguments);
        $compile(this.$tip)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        this.$tip.data('popover', this);
        return r;
      };
```

`scope.$digest()` is called after the `$compile`, which runs the embedded angular, but only for one digest loop. For some reason, the `$q` on line 542:

```js
   $q.when(options.content || $templateCache.get(value) || $http.get(value, { cache: true })).then(function onSuccess(template) {
```

Does not execute the `then` part until another `$scope.$digest` is called. Launching another `$digest` loop after a `$timeout` solves the problem:

```js
      popover.getPosition = function () {
        var r = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.getPosition.apply(this, arguments);
        $compile(this.$tip)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        $timeout(function () { scope.$digest(); }); // <-- The fix.
        this.$tip.data('popover', this);
        return r;
      };
```

Here is a version which works after this tweak with the library: http://plnkr.co/edit/KHgyvUOhreT8sG7RECpU

However, I suspect that this does not fully solve the problem since this only runs the `$digest` loop twice. I have to think more about how to solve this problem properly. This might be related to this issue: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/255

I would recommend trying out [`ui-bootstrap`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) which does not depend on `bootstrap.js` at all and integrated better with `angular.js`.